# static homepage no longer shows

Tags: homepage

Hi for some reason my hero theme doesn't show the static homepage anymore, Instead I now get a wordpress page. How do I get my home page back?

many thanks

ged

Answer (score 0):

You must have assigned a menu from wordpress dashboard and the pages there won't list your static homepage.
whichever is your homepage static template, at top include

```
<?php
/*  Template Name: Home Page
*/
```

Now you will need to create a page in wordpress and select page template as Home. Don't forget to assign that page to nav menu from wordpress backend

This should work in normal cases.
If it doesn't work, please describe how you did things.